# Running Sinatra on port 80

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I installed Sinatra and it works but it uses port 4567 by default. I want it to run on port 80.

In an effort to get it to work on port 80, I tried this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rack/handler/webrick'
require 'sinatra'

Sinatra::Application.default_options.merge!(
  :run => false,
  :env => :production,
  :port => 80
)

get '/' do
  "Hello World"
end
```

But I get this error:

```
$ ruby -rubygems index.rb
index.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `default_options' for Sinatra::Application:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Since you are running Ruby 1.9, note that you no longer need to `require 'rubygems'`; they're included in 1.9 for you. You also do not need to require 'webrick', Sinatra will do that as a fallback if a better server (like Thin) isn't installed.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Can't you just use (http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html):

```
set :port, 80
```

Note that in order to bind a socket to port 80, you'll need to have superuser privileges.

---

And, by the way,

> Using Sinatra.default_options to set base configuration items is obsolete

From: http://www.sinatrarb.com/one-oh-faq

Comment: When I try to do that: `/home/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/utils.rb:73:in `initialize': Permission denied - bind(2) (Errno::EACCES)`

Comment: To bind to anything below port 1024, you need to run as root.

Comment: @JasonSwett That either means that you already have a web server running on port 80, or you need to run the script as a super user to be allowed to set up on port 80.

Comment: I have Apache already running on port 80. I guess I'll just try stupid `mod_ruby` some more.

Comment: @Jason: Or just stop apache (if you can). Or, use apache rewrites. I once used them on a subdomain (ruby ran on port 18080): `.htaccess` looked like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:18080/$1 [P] [QSA]`.

Comment: @Jason: Passenger might be a better option, it works with Sinatra. Their documentation includes instructions on using Sinatra: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

Answer (score 18):

***An alternate way to accepted answer***

```
rvmsudo rackup -p 80
```

In case one is using RVM to manage Ruby versions, you may not be able to use sudo that easily (or else would need to setup ruby in path).

Answer (score 2):

Any port below 1024 is for privileged processes only.  You'd have to run as root to run the sinatra app directly on 80.  You could reverse proxy - http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, running anything other than Apache, Nginx, Varnish or HAProxy or port 80 is in my opiniona dangerous game. Those tools are very good at what they do. A reverse proxy setup is the way to go.