# allow others to see your Sinatra local server through amazon instance

Tags: ruby, ssh, sinatra

It's really difficult to explain.  But basically, I have an amazon instance, and I want to ssh into it and run a local server on it with sinatra.  so I would ssh into the amazon instance, git clone my repo, and run ruby config.ru.  Then I want someone else to be able to see that exact local server that is being ran.  One of the things I've done is added a security group, port 4567 HTTP so that I can access it via public dns.  It works on a rack app but it doesn't work on the sinatra, I've even tried a 'hello world' sample app to try to get it working.

Comment: Have you installed the Bundler gem?

Comment: of course, the main problem is I cant access the running local server from a different computer

Comment: OK, just checking. Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4821466/335847)?

Comment: yes, and to fix my post, I don't have to put it on port 80, any port is fine as long as add the rule to the amazon instance.  I pretty much haven't done anything different with the sinatra app as it's working completely find on a local server.

Comment: Are you using the Sinatra built in server (e.g. runnig `ruby myapp.rb`)? If so are you running in the default `development` environment or are you running in `production`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a specific reason that you want to do this from an Amazon server or not, but if you just want someone else to see your sinatra app, you could simply use [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/).

Using this, you can simply run localhost on your OWN computer, then run `localtunnel PORTNUMBER` and it will give you a URL that your app will now be visible from. You can then give that URL to anyone you want.

*Example of use:*

`$ ruby myapp.rb`

`$ localtunnel 4567`

A URL will then be displayed for you to copy-paste to a friend. Easy as that.

I use this a lot when developing web apps to be mobile friendly and want to quickly look at the app on my phone without having to deploy to a server.

Comment: perfect, yea that was what I needed.  also for some reason on my config.ru I can't do 'Sinatra::Application.run!', I have to just leave  it as 'Sinatra::Application' and it ran.  thanks